# I want to aggregate the information on two different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have two tables as below and I want to get a result like

**first table ->**

```
name    properties  piece
A            X       50
B            Y       40
A            Z       20
B            Y       10
A            X       15
```

**Second table ->**

```
name    properties  piece
A            X       10
B            Y       10
A            Z       10
B            Y       15
```

**The result I want to have**

```
name    properties  piece
A            X       55
A            Z       10
B            Y       40
```

Calc for A-X (50+15-10=5)

Comment: And what´s your problem? What have you tried? We´re not doing your job, you have to provide some idea.

Comment: You mean the pieces need to be added in the first table and subtracted when there is a match in the second table?

Comment: The last row result is not as per your provided logic shouldn't it be 25 ?

Comment: @HimBromBeere Plainly, that's not really true :-(

Comment: You have no PRIMARY KEY here, which may prove problematic.

Comment: Also, I don't understand the calculation for B

Comment: @SOreadytohelp right  B            Y       25

Comment: I have the first id I have not written here. not to be confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select name, properties, sum(piece) from (
  select name, properties, piece from first_table 
  union all 
  select name, properties, -1 * piece from second_table
) a 
group by name, properties
```

This would do

Comment: You beat me to it. Your answer would be even greater when you add a explainment

Comment: @RaymondNijland I was thinking the same. But could not get any better explanation for the queries which are already self explanatory.